# how to create a view model and rest api call in xamarin forms in MVVM

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I have an api URL [here](http://bresa.lazyhost.in/api/banners) which provides the response below.

> Json

```
{"status":200,"message":"Operation done successfully","data":{"enableNext":false,"products":[{"image":"http://bresa.lazyhost.in/upload/product/1/Tjtqr8.jpg","id":1,"code":"PROi6v8X5261","name":"Spandex Stretch Lounge Sofa with Couch Seat Cover SlipCover","description":"nice sofa , very comfortable for sitting in Living room","tags":"chairs, sofa, ","price":"1000.00","quantity":100,"images":["http://bresa.lazyhost.in/upload/product/1/Tjtqr8.jpg"]}]}}
```

The model class for above response is below.

> CarouselModel

```
namespace CameliaMaison.Models
{
     public partial class CarouselModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<CarouselData> Carouseldata { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CarouselData
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> The ViewModel

```
namespace CameliaMaison.ViewModels
{
    public class CarouselImagesViewModel
    {

        private List<CarouselData> items;

        public List<CarouselData> Items
        {
            get { return items; }
            set
            {

                items = value;
            }
        }

        public CarouselImagesViewModel()
        {
            var responseObj = MyHTTP.GetApiData().Result;
            foreach(CarouselData item in responseObj){
                Items.Add(item);
            }    
        }
    }

    public class MyHTTP
    {
        public static async Task<List<CarouselData>> GetApiData()
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://bresa.lazyhost.in/api/banners");
            CarouselModel categoriesData = new CarouselModel();
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                categoriesData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarouselModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            return categoriesData.Carouseldata;
        }

    }
}
```

I need to parse the JSON and store in Model Object and populate the data in the listview via MVVM.However, there seems to be something wrong with the implementation. I am unable to figure out and the content page class is below.

> ProductsListPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ProductsListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductsListPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
```

> ProductsListPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:CameliaMaison;assembly=CameliaMaison"
x:Class="CameliaMaison.Views.ProductsListPage"
Title="Employee List">
  <ListView x:Name="ListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="ABC" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but StackOverflow is not meant to be coding as a service. We will need more info on what you have tried, where you have failed and how you expect us to help. For more pointers on how to ask a proper question, please have a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - I have Edited the above question as per the rules.

Comment: I Couldnot see the linking of Viewmodel with the page in the above code

Comment: Using .Result is bad

Answer (score 0):

First you must have a button on your view page.

```
<Button Command = "{Binding GetInfoCommand}" />
```

Than you must create a view-model. Something like this :

```
public class CarouselModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //get a reference from the another class where you make the call to get the json
    Tasks ts = new Tasks();
    List<CarouselData> _carouseldata ;

    public List<CarouselData> CarouselData
    {
        get { return _carouseldata ; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _carouseldata ) return;
            _carouseldata = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand GetIInfoComand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async()=>
            {
                CarouselData= await _apiServices.GetInfo();
            });
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Than in your tasks.cs class you must consume the call where you get the json. This simple. :)

==edit==

In your view you must replace your `textcell`.Something like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextCell Text="{Binding Name }" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Also you get a reference of your view model and place it before the listview :

```
        <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <CarouselModel/>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that binding to a command from button need to be like this: Command="{Binding GetInfoCommand}", not like you mentioned: Command = "Binding GetInfoCommand"

Comment: Also better solution is to use ObservableCollection because ObservableCollection already implements INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: yes you're totally right @AlmirVuk . Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @IdevDev is it mandatory to have a action for each data binding?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no it is not mandatory. But what is the idea of using data-binding if not using actions to get data you need?

Comment: @IdevDev please have a look at the question which is more similar to my problem stackoverflow.com/q/51079625/7124761. It would be more grateful if you can suggest anything!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I'll try to help you in 2 hours because right now I'm not on my pc. :)

Comment: Yes, loves to hear from you!

Comment: I want to populate another class i would have done api.validateuser before and returned a user how do i do that now

Comment: But what if ur not calling from a button u still need a way to call api async